# Changing where clause without generating subquery in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, select, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a relatively complex query and would like to manipulate the where clause of the result directly, without cloning/subquerying the returned query. An example would look like:

```
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

    def generate_complex_query():
        return select(
            columns=[location.c.id.label('id')], 
            from_obj=location,
            whereclause=location.c.id>50
        ).alias('a')

    query = generate_complex_query()
    # based on this query, I'd like to add additional where conditions, ideally like:
    # `query.where(query.c.id<100)`
    # but without subquerying the original query

    # this is what I found so far, which is quite verbose and it doesn't solve the subquery problem
    query = select(
        columns=[query.c.id],
        from_obj=query,
        whereclause=query.c.id<100
    )

    # Another option I was considering was to map the query to a class:
    #   class Location(object):pass
    #   mapper(Location, query)
    #   session.query(Location).filter(Location.id<100)
    # which looks more elegant, but also creates a subquery

    result = session.execute(query)

    for r in result:
        print r
```

This is the generated query:

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM (SELECT location.id AS id 
FROM location 
WHERE location.id > %(id_1)s) AS a 
WHERE a.id < %(id_2)s
```

I would like to obtain:

```
SELECT location.id AS id 
FROM location 
WHERE id > %(id_1)s and
id < %(id_2)s
```

Is there any way to achieve this? The reason for this is that I think query (2) is slightly faster (not much), and the mapper example (2nd example above) which I have in place messes up the labels (`id` becomes `anon_1_id` or `a.id` if I name the alias).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do it like this:

```
query = generate_complex_query()
query = query.where(location.c.id < 100)
```

Essentially you can refine any query like this. Additionally, I suggest reading the [SQL Expression Language Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/tutorial.html) which is pretty awesome and introduces all the techniques you need. The way you build a `select` is only one way. Usually, I build my queries more like this: `select(column).where(expression).where(next_expression)` and so on. The `FROM` is usually automatically inferred by SQLAlchemy from the context, i.e. you rarely need to specify it.

Since you don't have access to the internals of `generate_complex_query` try this:

```
query = query.where(query.c.id < 100)
```

This should work in your case I presume.

Another idea:

```
query = query.where(text("id < 100"))
```

This uses SQLAlchemy's [text](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=.text#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) expression. This could work for you, however, and this is **important**: If you want to introduce variables, read the description of the API linked above, because just using format strings intead of *bound parameters* will open you up to SQL injection, something that normally is a no-brainer with SQLAlchemy but must be taken care of if working with such literal expressions.

Also note that this works because you label the column as `id`. If you don't do that and don't know the column name, then this won't work either.

Comment: What do you get as query result? A number of nested subqueries or a 'AND'ed where clause?

Comment: Ahh... You're using `location.c.id` as column to select on. Unfortunately, I don't have any insights of what's going on in `generate_complex_query`, so won't be able to access any table columns of it...

Comment: Thanks @javex. The problem with this approach is that it's wrapping the original query into a subquery and creates new column labels (see the first query in my post).

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong in the way, I am constructing the original query. I return `select(columns=[location.c.id.label('id')], from_obj=location, whereclause=location.c.id > 50)` in the query constructing function.

Comment: @orange No the query is perfectly fine. I'd build it similarly, resulting in the same query. I will add a new approach that might work for you using literal SQL.

Comment: I was trying out `query.append_whereclause()`in the meantime, but this causes an infinite recursion.

Comment: No, I hadn't. Your edit works and it's easy to obtain the columns (`query.columns`), but I'm concerned about the issue of SQL injection as you mention. It surprises me that the literal clause works and when it comes to using the query object's columns, it generates a subquery. Could this be a bug?

Comment: @orange No, it makes total sense as you are acessing the column of a *query* not a *table*. Thus it has to build a subquery (which in turn behaves like a table in most places, e.g. you can join from the results and so on). On the issue of SQLinjection: Just use bound parameters, never something like `"id > %s" % id_`, as **this** will cause a security risk.

Comment: From that point of view it makes sense, but I was thinking (hoping) it would treat the query more like a table. Still, I think that `query.append_whereclause` should work, according to what I [read about it](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.append_whereclause) (it works when I use literals, but when passing in a `query.c.id<50`, it quits with a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp`).